# How do I view a JPEG's EXIF data in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, jpg

I would like to view a JPEG's EXIF data in Gimp, perhaps modifying it.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can see the Exif data using File...Properties...Advanced. See also [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/are-there-gimp-plugins-that-allow-one-to-view-and-edit-exif-data).

Answer (score 3):

In GIMP 2.10.14: Image > Metadata[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is (in my GIMP 2.8.14, released for Mac OS X by http://gimp.lisanet.de) a menu Image --> View Exif; I don't know if this is an addition done by the maintainer of the OS X package or a GIMP proper.  However, there is a plugin ("Exif viewer") available from http://registry.gimp.org/node/8839 .

Answer (score 1):

I have GIMP 2.10 on another machine (LINUX MINT 19) and a GIMP 2.10 version feature is access to EXIF data.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Many tool is available for open exif file and edit exif file in market as well as they are able to save exif images into many format like jpg, png, gimp etc.
You can download [exif viewer](http://www.freeviewer.org/exif/) from the internet.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question is about modifying EXIF from Gimp, not just modifying it in general.

Comment: Hi Sandra, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your input. As Scribblemacher says, this doesn't really answer the question of how to edit the EXIF data in GIMP. If you can [edit] your answer to include that info, please do. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!